# ¿ Cómo crear una lista a partir de una lista con tupla?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito que a partir de esta lista:

```
cortes=[’raspall’, ’garson’, ’mao-tse’, ’punki’, ’kunki’]
```

Y de esta lista con tuplas:

```
prop=[(’mao-tse’, 2), (’raspall’, 5), (’raspall’, 2), (’garson’, 10),(’mao-tse’, 6),
(’kunki’, 3)]
```

Me muestre una lista como esta:

```
[ [’raspall’, 7], [’garson’, 10], [’mao-tse’, 8], [’punki’, 0], [’kunki’, 3] ]
```

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Me había confundido, ya esta editado. Me tiene que mostrar una lista con cada corte, por ejemplo en prop mao-tse sale dos veces con 2 y 6, entonces en la lista final tendría que salir "mao-tse:8

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado para lograrlo? ¿Dónde está el error? ¿Por qué debe darte ese resultado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma muy concisa sería la siguiente:

```
cortes=['raspall', 'garson', 'mao-tse', 'punki', 'kunki']
prop=[('mao-tse', 2), ('raspall', 5), ('raspall', 2), ('garson', 10),('mao-tse', 6), ('kunki', 3)]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in prop:
  if k in cortes:
    d[k]+=v

print(list(d.items()))
```

```
[('mao-tse', 8), ('raspall', 7), ('garson', 10), ('kunki', 3)]
```

### Explicación

Utilizo un `defaultdict` que es un tipo de datos python equivalente al diccionario, pero que no da error si intentas acceder a una clave que no existe, sino que te da un valor por defecto. La variable en cuestión es `d`. Si intentamos mirar `d['foobar']`, ya que esa clave no existe, me da el valor por defecto, que es 0 porque especifiqué al crearlo que fuera `int`.

Eso me permite acumular (sumar) en ese diccionario con una expresión como `d[k]+=v`, ya que si `k` no existía, asumirá el valor 0, le sumará `v` y dejará ese resultado en la clave `k`, que a partir de ese momento ya existirá.

Con ese truco basta recorrer la lista `prop`, separando sus tuplas en dos variables `k` y `v` (`k` para el nombre, `v` para el valor), y mirar si `k` está en `cortes` para añadirle el valor.

Una vez hayamos terminado, `list(d.items())` convierte el diccionario que guarda los resultados en una lista de tuplas.

## Actualización

El usuario pregunta cómo hacerlo sin importar módulos extra (aunque el módulo `collections` forma parte del python estándar, no hay que instalar nada extra, pero bueno), sino usando sólo bucles y tipos "normales".

El código antes explicado puede adaptarse de forma trivial a estos requisitos. En lugar de `defaultdict` usamos un diccionario normal y simplemente metemos un 0 si la clave no existía previamente:

```
d = {} # Diccionario inicialmente vacío
for k, v in prop:
  if k in cortes:
    if k not in d:    # <--- esto es lo nuevo
      d[k] = 0        # <----
    d[k] += v
print(d)
```

```
{'mao-tse': 8, 'raspall': 7, 'garson': 10, 'kunki': 3}
```

En este caso imprimo directamente el diccionario resultado. Si quieres la lista de tuplas se obtendría como en la respuesta anterior.

Observa sin embargo que las claves que no aparecen en `prop`, tampoco aparecerán en el resultado (como por ejemplo `punki`). Si quieres que aparezcan con contador cero, una opción es preparar antes el diccionario con ceros en todas esas claves:

```
d = {}

# Primero poner un 0 en todas las claves
for k in cortes:
  d[k] = 0

# Ahora sumarles los valores que vayamos encontrando.
for k, v in prop:
  if k in cortes:
    d[k]+=v

print(d)
```

```
{'raspall': 7, 'garson': 10, 'mao-tse': 8, 'punki': 0, 'kunki': 3}
```

Fíjate que si en `prop` apareciera algún nombre no presente en `cortes`, éste no sería parte del resultado, que supongo que es lo que se pide.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero  como lo podría hacer sin tener que importar nada ?, es decir, simplemente usando for y cosas sencillas.

Comment: @Marc Respuesta actualizada, pero no veo por qué no usar las ventajas que Python te ofrece, como los defaultdicts.

Comment: @Benito-B Esta respuesta mia es de 2018. Era más ingenuo yo entonces...

Answer (score 2):

Otra solución

```
# creamos un diccionario con las claves de la lista dándole un valor por defecto
result = dict.fromkeys(cortes, 0)
# recorremos cada uno de los elementos de la lista y modificamos el d
for p in prop:
    result[p[0]] += p[1]
# obtenemos una lista de tuplas con los datos
print (result.items())
```

> [('raspall', 7), ('punki', 0), ('kunki', 3), ('garson', 10), ('mao-tse', 8)]

Y si lo que quieres es una lista de listas:

```
[list(x) for x in result.items()]
```

> [['raspall', 7], ['punki', 0], ['kunki', 3], ['garson', 10], ['mao-tse', 8]]